# Néron–Tate height with respect to a positive divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, arithmetic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry

In section 3 of the paper [Canonical heights on varieties with morphisms](http://www.numdam.org/article/CM_1993__89_2_163_0.pdf), page 180 after equation (26), the writers say: “The height function with respect to a positive divisor is bounded below off of the support of the divisor, and for an ample divisor is everywhere bounded below.”

I don’t see why it’s true. Are there any references for this claim?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any textbook should discuss this fact, I think? See for instance *Diophantine Geometry: An Introduction* by Hindry and Silverman.

Comment: I have a similar book by Lang, “Fundamentals of Diophantine Geometry” and I couldn’t find any such reference. Do you know any specific ones?

Comment: I just checked; it’s definitely in Hindry-Silverman. See page 185.